# phantom jar in maven build overriding modified jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, war

I have a basic project setup

`first.jar` -> is a util jar

`second.war`-> is a web harness that uses util.jar

both are maven project where I pull in `first.jar` as a dependency . I have modified first.jar and it works fine (standalone) but when I try and use the modified functions through the web harness it seems to be accessing an old version of the jar . I tried changing `first.jar's` release number to be sure and made that a dependency in the `second.jar` . I also checked the files in the WAR made by second project and the jar in the web-inf seems to reflect the changes I made but still does not work when I use the war . I am thoroughly confused on what the issue could be but I suspect the war is pulling a cached/phantom copy of the jar . I am using IntelliJ as an IDE.

Comment: What is your process for running WAR?

Comment: deploying it on tomcat